# Given the positions of opening brackets, find out where each of these needs to close

Tags: python, algorithm, function

I am trying to solve the following challenge:

> Imagine a list of opening brackets and as many closing brackets in some valid order. For example:
>
> ```
>  (  (  (  )  )  (  )  )
> ```
>
> We can map each opening bracket with its corresponding closing bracket by giving such bracket pairs unique, sequential numbers, in the order in which they are opened. For the above example that encoding would be:
>
> ```
> [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 0]
> ```
>
> The input will provide all the indices at which opening brackets occur, in left-to-right order. For the above example, the input would be:
>
> ```
> [0, 1, 2, 5]
> ```
>
> The challenge is to reconstruct from that input the encoding given above:
>
> ```
> [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 0]
> ```

### My approach

The key observation is that the first closed bracket needs to be connected by an arc to the immediately preceding open bracket. (Otherwise, there would necessarily be a crossing of arcs!) Equivalently, the last open bracket needs to be connected by an arc to the immediately succeeding closed bracket. This can be done iteratively by drawing arcs and considering the remaining available brackets.

In our example, `0,1,2,*,*,3,*,*` would successively transition to `0,1,2,*,*,3,3,*`, `0,1,2,2,*,3,3,*`, `0,1,2,2,1,3,3,*`, and finally `0,1,2,2,1,3,3,0`.

This brings me to the following algorithm:

1. Given the positions of n open brackets, create an list of length 2n filled with * denoting undetermined arc labels
2. For all open brackets, label the *i*'th open bracket with arc label *i*.
3. If there are no unmatched open brackets, return the arc labelling
4. Otherwise, for the last unmatched open bracket, find the first succeeding unmatched closed bracket and label it with the same arc label.
5. Repeat from step 2.

I tried to implement this algorithm, writing a function `arc_representation()` that takes a list of open bracket positions and returns an arc representation.

```
def arc_representation(c):
    n=len(c)
    arc=["*"]*2*n
    for i in range(n):
        print(arc)
        pos=c[i]
        arc[pos]=i
    for i in range(n-1,-1,-1):
        print(arc)
        pos=c[i]
        arc[pos]=i
        if arc[pos] == "*":
            arc[pos] = arc[pos-1]
            
    return arc

arc_representation([0,1,2,5])
```

It produces this output:

```
['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']
[0, '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']
[0, 1, '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']
[0, 1, 2, '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']
[0, 1, 2, '*', '*', 3, '*', '*']
[0, 1, 2, '*', '*', 3, '*', '*']
[0, 1, 2, '*', '*', 3, '*', '*']
[0, 1, 2, '*', '*', 3, '*', '*']
```

And so the returned list is:

```
[0, 1, 2, '*', '*', 3, '*', '*']
```

### Problem

I'm not getting the positions of the open brackets numbers at 0,1,2,5 in 3,4,6,7. The code has filled in the positions of open brackets with 0 to 3 at 0,1,2,5. Now I need to have the corresponding number to them which legal in terms of brackets, like this `((())()) = 01221330`.

I'm just struggling to replace the other * with the legal numbers. I know how to do it logically, but didn't manage to turn that into code. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It seems that you have already found out how to turn it into a function.

Comment: I have *no* idea what *brackets* the text refers to. If part of the text is from a third party, please use a block quote to make that eye catching and heed [How to reference material written by others](/help/referencing).

Comment: I find SE/SO questions work best with one answerable explicit question near the end of each question post. `struggling to fill the other * with the legal number` follow point 4 to the letter! In point 5, it is enough to repeat from point 3.

Comment: I edited your question and added an introduction to explain the code challenge. Please check if this is indeed how it should be understood.

Comment: @trincot yes, much better explanation than mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your attempt you have this piece of code:

```
        arc[pos]=i
        if arc[pos] == "*":
            arc[pos] = arc[pos-1]
```

But that `if` condition can never be True, as you had just placed a *number* `i` at that position, so it couldn't possibly be an asterisk. A slight improvement would be to look for the asterisk at the *next* index:

```
        arc[pos] = i
        if arc[pos+1] == "*":
            arc[pos+1] = i
```

This way you at least pair bracket pairs that have nothing inside them. To extend this, you could *find* the asterisk:

```
        arc[pos] = i
        j = arc.index("*", i + 1)
        arc[j] = i
```

With this change it will work.

You can avoid having to call `index` by using a stack that maintains the positions of non-closed brackets, while traversing the list from left to right. When you encounter an asterisk, pop the bracket number from the stack and place it there. If you read a bracket number, push it on the stack.

Note: I would not mix ints and strings in `arc`, so I would use -1 to mark the open slots in the list, not asterisks.

Code:

```
def arc_representation(c):
    arc = [-1]*2*len(c)

    for bracket, index in enumerate(c):
        arc[index] = bracket
    
    stack = []
    for index, bracket in enumerate(arc):
        if bracket == -1:
            arc[index] = stack.pop()
        else:
            stack.append(bracket)

    return arc

print(arc_representation([0,1,2,5]))  # [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 0]
```

Comment: @cosygod, you're welcome. Does it [answer your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: yes, certainly better than what i had in my mind.

Comment: oh didnt know i could do that, sure.